# Dialog with bottom gravity animates over navigation bar above api kitkat?

Tags: android, animation, dialog, navigationbar

I have to show a dialog like a bottom sheet with animation for that I have used the following code.

```
 View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_picker_bottom_sheet, null);
            Dialog mBottomSheetDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.MaterialDialogSheet);
            mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
            mBottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            mBottomSheetDialog.show();
```

**Dialog style**

```
 <!-- Bottom sheet style-->
    <style name="MaterialDialogSheet" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MaterialDialogSheetAnimation</item>
    </style>

 <!-- Animation-->
    <style name="MaterialDialogSheetAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_show</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_hide</item>
    </style>
```

And it works well but overlapping the navigation bar when entering with `windowEnterAnimation` and it's placing in the desired position after the animation, nothing problem with that.

How can I start the animation of dialog from the navigation bar without overlapping it when entering?

You can see the UI below it's placing correctly but when coming out it animates over navigation.

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Same, having this problem right now and would like to see an answer.

Comment: It looks like this is an [unresolved Android defect](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet/issues/9#issue) without a proper solution.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40361719/7292819) answer.  Put that line in the theme of the Activity you're putting the dialog in. It worked for me with the same problem.  @ZeekAran

Comment: @Gary99 that didn't work either.

Comment: @Christ, Did you find the solution now?